# How to improve SVM classifier which is based on HOG features for Pedestrian Detection?

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm, object-detection

I have trained an SVM Classifier with the help of this tutorial : [trainHOG Tutorial](https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG/wiki/trainHOG-Tutorial)

It created a `genfiles` dir which consists of `cvHOGClassifier.yaml`, `descriptorvector.dat`, `features.dat`, `svmlightmodel.dat` files.

I wrote the following code to test my model

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ml.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ml;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout << "Testing trained detector..." << endl;

    vector<float> descriptorVector;
    
    std::ifstream file("genfiles/descriptorvector.dat");
    
    float number;
    
    while(file >> number) 
    descriptorVector.push_back(number);
   
    HOGDescriptor hog;
    hog.winSize = Size(64, 128);
    
    hog.setSVMDetector(descriptorVector);

  
//  hog.load( "/home/nvidia/Desktop/HOG/genfiles/cvHOGClassifier.yaml" );

    VideoCapture cap("/home/nvidia/Desktop/test_videos/4.mp4");

    Mat img;
    Size size(1280,491);
    
    for(;;)
    {
     
    bool Is = cap.grab();
        
        if (Is == false) {
        cout << "Video Capture Fail" << endl;
        break;
        }
        
        else{
    
        cap.retrieve(img, CV_CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE);
        img  = imread("queue.jpg");
        resize(img,img,size);
        cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        vector< Rect > detections;
        vector< double > foundWeights;

        Size padding(Size(8, 8));
        Size winStride(Size(8, 8));
        hog.detectMultiScale(img, detections, 0, winStride, padding);   
  

       vector<Rect> found_filtered;
       size_t i, j;

       for (i = 0; i < detections.size(); ++i) {
        Rect r = detections[i];
        for (j = 0; j < detections.size(); ++j)
            if (j != i && (r & detections[j]) == r)
                break;
        if (j == detections.size())
            found_filtered.push_back(r);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < found_filtered.size(); i++) {
        Rect r = found_filtered[i];
        rectangle(img, r.tl(), r.br(), Scalar(64, 255, 64), 3);
    }
    

        imshow( "Streaming", img );

        int key1 = waitKey(20);
            }
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives me **only** false positives. I have trained the model with 15k positives 64x128 images and 3k negatives 64x128 images. Going through various Q&A's on SO didn't help much to my scenario.

**What modifications should I do to make my model work properly?**

Comment: try [ssd_mobilenet_object_detection.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/ssd_mobilenet_object_detection.cpp) probably you will give up training HOG detector.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that model is just overfitted. From what I saw in this tutorial code they use svmlight and just load data and train. This might be too little. Traning good svm model isn't so simply (sadly). There are some things in there which you may consider:

1. First of all you traning data is inbalanced (15k positive vs 3k
   negative). You would be better with selecting some subset of those
   positive samples (you can even try to select 3k of positive samples
   randomly). Balancing of traning data is important.
2. Second thing to consider is doing some crossvalidation on this
   dataset to search for good parameters of model. (see 3. for more info)
3. What kernel you are using? Is your data separably linearly? If not
   then you should probably start with RBF kernel and see if it is any
   better (remember to find gamma and C with crossvalidation procedure)

Also as you are using opencv it comes with it owns SVM. I am not sure which version of OpenCv you use but here try to start with this tutorial (opencv 3.0 there should be no change in between 3.0 and 3.4 in svm)

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/ml/non_linear_svms/non_linear_svms.html

If for some reason you cannot use opencv implementation it will still be benefitial for you to look into how to train good model. Here is very good tutorial to understand svm (it is from authors of libSvm on which opencv implementation is based):

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf